# odoo iframe not accepting "?" in url

Tags: iframe, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I am using iframe in my view.

I am getting this message from odoo log :
XMLSyntaxError: EntityRef: expecting ';', line 43, column 53 ( line 43, column 53 is pointing to "?")

but if i make the url short or remove the "?" it works fine.

```
     <record id="view_complaints_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">complaints.form</field>
        <field name="model">complaints</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Embedded Webpage" version="7.0"  edit="false">
    <iframe marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder = "0" 
            src="myurl.com/index.php?view=cycle&group=0" width="100%" height="1000"/>
</form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Answer (score 1):

The ampersand symbol `&` has a special meaning (entity reference) in this context within XML and [cannot be used plainly](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xml-20001006#syntax), so it must be escaped:

```xml
<iframe marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder="0" 
        src="myurl.com/index.php?view=cycle&amp;group=0" width="100%" height="1000"/>
```

You are getting the `XMLSyntaxError: EntityRef: expecting ';'`, because the ampersand denotes the start of an entity reference, but there is no reference name and the semicolon is missing. `&amp;` is the entity reference for the ampersand itself.